# How to change HTTP status codes from inside an OpenWhisk action

Tags: openwhisk

Trying to change http status code from an openWhisk web action through api connect

here's my openWhisk action :

```
function main() {
  return {
    statusCode: 400
  }
}
```

and connected to an api endpoint `/secure`

so hitting `/secure` always returns a 200 instead of 400 and the action's output is added to the response payload.

what could I've done wrong?

Comment: Have you created the action as a web action?

Comment: @markusthoemmes Yes, I can't use it in the api connect if its not a web action

Answer (score 2):

Create an action with following code:

```
function main(){
  return ({
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        statusCode: 200,
        body: new Buffer(JSON.stringify("Hello World")).toString('base64')
      });
};
```

Call it as a web action with `http` as extension.
To know more about context extension, read [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_webactions.html#additional-features) if you haven't already.

In this case if you change the status code from `200` to `400` you will see the difference. 
If I am not wrong, you need to include header in the return block.